# Apache FOP / custom image does not show in PDF

Tags: apache-fop

With FOP 2.6 I try to convert an FO file to a PDF.
I use the standard configuration file on Windows.

As one image format is not supported, I created a custom PreLoader, ImageLoaderFactory and ImageConverter.
They are registered via service entries and from the logs I can see they are beeing used:

```
DEBUG: Chosen pipeline: Loader: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderRaw@2dad1d4c Converters: [image.loader.custom.ImageConverterCustom2PNG@26080b64]
DEBUG: Creating new Source for figure\sb.custom
DEBUG: convert custom image: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageRawStream: figure\sb.custom (image/custom)
DEBUG: custom image converted to png
DEBUG: Image is made cacheable: figure\sb.custom (image/custom)
DEBUG: New ImageAdapter created for key: figure\sb.custom
INFO: Rendered page #86.
```

But the image does not show up in the generated PDF file...

The converter converts the custom format to PNG and returns RAW_PNG:

```
ByteArrayInputStream convertedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outBuffer.toByteArray());
PNGFile pngFile = new PNGFile(convertedStream, originalInfo.getOriginalURI());
ImageRawPNG image = pngFile.getImageRawPNG(originalInfo);
```

I have also tried to convert to JPG also with no success.

Using the converted file directly does work:
Instead of:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(figure\sb.custom)" width="auto" height="auto" content-width="160mm" content-height="auto"/>
```

This:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(custom.png)" width="auto" height="auto" content-width="160mm" content-height="auto"/>
```

Shows the image.

Are the converters not being chained?
Or do I miss something crucial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the root cause.
My image preloader was missing these lines when createing the image size:

```
size.setResolution(context.getSourceResolution());
size.calcSizeFromPixels();
```